# PHP - Convert Tab Delimited TXT file to CSV

Tags: php, csv

I'm trying to convert a tab delimited .txt file into a .csv file.

I was able to use fgetcsv() to open the txt file and get the data for each line with the following code:

```
$handle = fopen("fileurl.com", "r");
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("fileurl.com", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;

        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }

        print_r($data);

    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Now i just need to create a csv file from the data array. I've tried using fputcsv(), but haven't had any luck. I've tried something like this, but the csv file it creates isn't correct and only has 1 row:

```
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

fputcsv($fp, $data, "\t");

fclose($fp);
```

An example of how to create a .csv file from the $data array would be great. I've spent a lot of time researching and trying to get this figured out, but haven't been able to get it working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`fputcsv()` only writes one line at a time. Not the whole file. You you need to loop through `$data` in order to add all of that data into your CSV file.

```
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
foreach ($data as $line) {
    fputcsv($fp, $line);
}
fclose($fp);
```

A full example using your code:

```
$handle = fopen("fileurl.com", "r");
$lines = [];
if (($handle = fopen("fileurl.com", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
        $lines[] = $data;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    fputcsv($fp, $line);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this and get the following error:
Warning: fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given

Comment: I updated my answer you use your code as an example. You were not putting the data into an array which is needed for this to work.

Comment: That gets a Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on this line $fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

Comment: Change `$data` to `$lines`

Comment: along with it $attachment = mb_convert_encoding($attachment, 'UTF-8', $parts[$i]->parameters[0]->value); also needed for tsv to csv. it will change file type to text/plain

Comment: Works like a charm!!

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to write data into csv file

```
    <?php

$list = array (
    array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

In fputcsv we use second parameter as an array .

Answer (score 0):

along with it $attachment = mb_convert_encoding($attachment, 'UTF-8', $parts[$i]->parameters[0]->value); also needed for tsv to csv. it will change file type to text/plain