# Convert Comma Delimited To Tab Delimited Using PHP

Tags: php, csv, amazon-mws

I'm trying to upload a file to Amazon MWS. I get an inventory file in .csv format like this:

**feed.csv**

```
sku,qty
ABC,5
HHA,8
```

How can I convert this to tab delimited when I read it in like this:

```
$file = file_get_contents('feed.csv', 'r') or die("cant open file");

echo($file);
```

Comment: use `preg_replace` which specifically has a tab character.

Comment: str_replace(oldvalue,newvalue,string)

Comment: @Martin What about values that have a comma in them? I would suggest using fgetcsv to load the file into an array, then use fputcsv to output it with a tab delimiter.

Comment: If the file isn't any more complex than that, you can just replace the delimiter. If there are also quoted columns/etc, you can use `fgetcsv` and `fputcsv` to maintain the integrity..

Comment: @RToyo you are of course correct; I was assuming the OP was aware of this obvious issue. The question seemed to hinge on how to identify tab characters.

Comment: `fgetcsv` and `fputcsv` are fraught with consitency problems and UTF-8 issues. I've found it has always been more efficient, less error prone to manually construct the CSV file with `file_put_contents` ....

Comment: What is that 'r' in `file_get_contents`? Just curious.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810370/php-convert-tab-delimited-txt-file-to-csv

Answer (score 1):

If you have no other commas, the easy way is to replace all commas with tabs:

```
$file = str_replace(',', "\t", $file);
```

A more complete solution would be to use `fgetcsv` to read the file, and then create a tab-delimited csv from the read data with `fputcsv`.